# Self defined function works on whole data frame but not on grouped data frame (applied with 'groupby' function) in Python

Tags: python, function, pandas-groupby

I have a simple data frame which I wish to apply `groupby` function on column 'A' and generate new column calculated from defined function (loop within the function) that takes values from column 'B' and column 'C'. My problem is, I was able to able the function to whole data frame but not to grouped data frame (`Exception: Column(s) B already selected`). I don't why it throws error on grouped data frame but not on whole data frame. My implementation is as below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.read_csv("foo.txt", sep="\t")
>>> df
   A  B   C
0  1  4   3
1  1  5   4
2  1  2  10
3  2  7   2
4  2  4   4
5  2  6   6
>>>
>>> def calc(data):
...         length = len(data['B'])
...         mx = data['B'][0]
...         nx = data['C'][0]
...         for i in range(1,length):
...                 my = data['B'][i]
...                 ny = data['C'][i]
...                 nx = nx + ny
...                 mx=(mx*nx+my*ny)/(nx+ny)
...         return(mx)
...
>>> df_grouped = df.groupby(['A'])
>>> calc(df)
4.217694879423274
>>> calc(df_grouped)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in calc
  File "/mnt/projects/kokep/kokep/devel/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 250, in __getitem__
    .format(selection=self._selection))
Exception: Column(s) B already selected
>>>
```

How can I get it worked? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you should work with every group separatelly.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I think `reset_index` function need to be applied for each of the groups:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.read_csv("foo.txt", sep="\t")
>>> df
   A  B   C
0  1  4   3
1  1  5   4
2  1  2  10
3  2  7   2
4  2  4   4
5  2  6   6
>>>
>>> def calc(data):
...         length = len(data['B'])
...         mx = data['B'][0]
...         nx = data['C'][0]
...         for i in range(1,length):
...                 my = data['B'][i]
...                 ny = data['C'][i]
...                 nx = nx + ny
...                 mx=(mx*nx+my*ny)/(nx+ny)
...         return(mx)
...
>>> result = []
>>> for name, group in df.groupby('A'):
...         group = pd.DataFrame(group).reset_index()
...         out = calc(group)
...         result.append(out)
...
>>> result
[3.488215488215488, 5.866666666666666]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your groupby is producing pandas.series and your function is not applied on this series. I tried playing with different groupby methods, for some reason it's not working. Once I find the solution, I will post it here.